# Get related information from homesite

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a filtered lookup field in a sharepoint list that displays a list of stores from another site in the same site collection and I need to know which region the store belong to which is part of the record.
Home site list

```
 **Store     Region**
  Halifax     Atlantic
  Toronto     Central
  Calgary     Western
```

Sub Site list for store requests

```
 - Request type = inventory     Store = from filtered lookup   Region = ???
```

How can I get the associated region from the home site
SharePoint foundation

Thanks Jinx

Answer (score 1):

You can use SPServices in order to achieve this 
Follow this link http://coresharepoint.blogspot.com/2012/07/using-spservices-to-query-list-in.html

Here there are 2 lists

> coolcities - equivalent to "Home site list"
>
> selected cities - equivalent to "Sub Site list"

Hope this helps!